# is it possible to perform a SQL Injection through a XSS vulnerability?

Tags: security, xss, sql-injection

I've tried to perform a SQL Injection pentest on a website but couldn't because the website was not vulnerable. I want to try to perform a SQL Injection pentest through a XSS vulnerability. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSS allows an attacker to trick your website display to insert Javascript code where you had expected to output plain text.

In theory, the Javascript could create an AJAX request back to the website, and try to make a POST request with malicious content containing SQL syntax to an AJAX endpoint, and the code for that endpoint use the content in an SQL query.

But if the SQL queries on the website are not vulnerable to SQL injection already, then Javascript can't make them vulnerable.